# Name for the set of vertices with the same neighborhood as another vertex

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a simple graph and $N_{\Gamma}(g)=\{x\in V(\Gamma)|x\sim g\}$ is the neighborhood of $g\in V(\Gamma)$. Then consider 
$$\mathbb{S}=\{y\in V(\Gamma)|N_{\Gamma}(y)=N_{\Gamma}(g)\}.$$
Is there a name in graph theory for the set $\mathbb{S}$?

Comment: Every vertex in $\mathbb{S}$ is usually called a *twin* of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I will make my comment into an answer.  The set of vertices with the same neighbourhood as a fixed vertex $g$, are called *twins* of $g$.  If $x$ and $y$ are adjacent vertices of $\Gamma$ and $N_\Gamma(x) \cup \{x\}=N_\Gamma(y) \cup \{y\}$, then $x$ and $y$ are sometimes called *adjacent twins*.  A nice use of adjacent twins is the Replication Lemma of Lovász, in his proof of the Weak Perfect Graph Conjecture.

**Replication Lemma**. Let $G$ be a perfect graph and $x \in V(G)$.  If $G'$ is obtained from $G$ by adding a new vertex $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ are adjacent twins in $G'$, then $G'$ is also perfect.